# Python data scraping with beautiful soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Hi all I am new to Python. Please let me know how to scrap data from below code section using beautiful soup.

```
<Td class=cell>
<br>
<blockquote>
<p><B>Question:</b> Which is the world's leading egg-producing         country?</p>
<p><ol><li><label for="q1824-1"><input type=radio id="q1824-1" name=q1824  onClick="check_answer('q1824correct','q1824incorrect','1','1');">China
</label><br><li><label for="q1824-2"><input type=radio id="q1824-2"  name=q1824   onClick="check_answer('q1824correct','q1824incorrect','2','1');">India
</label><br><li><label for="q1824-3"><input type=radio id="q1824-3" name=q1824 onClick="check_answer('q1824correct','q1824incorrect','3','1');">Japan
</label><br><li><label for="q1824-4"><input type=radio id="q1824-4" name=q1824  onClick="check_answer('q1824correct','q1824incorrect','4','1');">Malaysia</label><br></ol></p>
```

The out put look like this

**Question:** Which is the world's leading egg-producing         country?

1. China

   India

   Japan

   Malaysia

Comment: What do you mean by `scrap data`? There is a lot of data in the example and we can't possibly know which is the one you care about. Also you should be the best one to explain the semantics of this data

Comment: I have changed it  please have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

It's very hard to know what exactly you want as your problem (as it currently stands) is very poorly defined.

Normally, the boilerplate for scrapingany HTML in BeautifulSoup is like this:

```
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
html_doc = response.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
```

You can then extract elements from the HTML based on different criteria, like so:

```
# this would match the top-level element in your snippet
# i.e. <td class="cell">
td_element = soup.find("td", _class="cell")

# this would match all of the <label> elements in your snippet
# (so you'll get a list as your result)
labels = soup.findAll("label")
```

Comment: Thanks it helped me lot